# Modificar llave variable cuyo valor es otro diccionario, en un ciclo de inputs

Tags: python, archivo, bucles, diccionarios

Tengo un diccionario de la forma

```
dicc = {"identidad": {"dato1":valor1, "dato2":valor2, "dato3":valor3, "dato3":valor3}
```

Y necesito hacer que todos los valores sean ingresados por el usuario, para luego escribirlo en un archivo.
Todo el proceso de entrada de valores lo coloqué dentro de un `while True` para que se pueda hacer n cantidad de veces, de esta forma

```
while True:
    print("Digite el numero de identidad")
    identidad_entrada = input()
    dicc[identidad_entrada] = dicc.pop("identidad")
```

El problema es que al realizar un segundo ciclo para crear otra identidad, el nombre de la variable que originalmente era identidad ahora es distinto, entonces me salta error de que ahora es distinto y por ende `dicc[identidad_entrada] = dicc.pop("identidad")` no puede ocurrir.

Como puedo hacer que identidad vuelva siempre al estado original después de realizar un ciclo?
O de que otra manera podría solucionar esto?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿No será `identidad_entrada`?

Comment: no sé porque eliminas datos si lo ue quieres es insertar